# QuillJS: dangerouslyPasteHTML adds \n before and after <ul>

Tags: quill

Using dangerouslyPasteHTML keeps adding \n before a `<ul>` and after `</ul>`

See https://jsfiddle.net/lidbanger/pyo5ekub/

Quill initially loads with the content `<p>Hello World!</p><ul><li>Apples</li><li>Pears</li><li>Oranges</li></ul>`

Click the "Get HTML" button [ `document.getElementById("editor").childNodes[0].innerHTML` ]

Click the "Set HTML" button [ `quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(0, sHTML)` ]

Repeat.

A `<p><br></p>` is prepended and appended to the  after each use of the aptly named dangerouslyPasteHTML.

I'd expect quill to respect the HTML markup and not add the `<p><br></p>`

Google Chrome: 56.0.2924.87

Quill.version:1.2.0

Comment: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1326

Comment: Hmm. Is it be possible to disable this feature? Consider the situation where Quill is being used to edit content where it's final presentation will be in HTML.

Comment: When Quill renders the HTML it'll add the extra '\n'. The host page will then consider that the content has changed and save the modified content. Next time the Quill loads the updated content it'll append another set of '\n'. Repeat ad infinitum for double infinite white space - which can't be a good thing surely :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set the content of Quill directly with HTML. Use the API instead !

```js
// Set HTML content and API content (ops) as form values
// e.g. to POST it to a database:
myForm.content.value = document.querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML;
var ops = Editor.getContents().ops;
theForm.content_raw.value = JSON.stringify(ops);
```

This way you have HTML content to show on your website and raw content to load in your Quill:

```js
// Load content into Quill
var editContent = JSON.parse(content_raw); // e.g. from a db query
Editor.setContents(editContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be disabled. For more info, see this link:
https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#matchvisual

Comment: ah hah! This makes Quill really useful again all of a sudden!

Comment: Indeed it does, lets vote for shift+enter support and we have a great editor that actually works :) Please mark answer as correct if you find that it helps, thanks!

Comment: The `matchVisual` option was removed in later versions. see [here](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/ee827ffb605ba491246f201d497ce0e7d9e193a0/docs/guides/upgrading-to-2-0.md#configuration).